# How can I switch between two background-colors using js setinterval()

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to Set two background-color in the javascript by setInterval()?

```js
    let x = document.body;
    x.style.backgroundColor = x.style.backgroundColor === "yellow" ? "pink": "yellow";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var i = 0;
function change() {
  var doc = document.getElementById("background");
  var color = ["black", "blue", "brown", "green"];
  doc.style.backgroundColor = color[i];
  i = (i + 1) % color.length;
}
setInterval(change, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="background">&nbsp</div>
```